# How to get jQuery EasyUI datagrid and treegrid to load in background?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am trying build a jQuery EasyUI datagrid or treegrid out of a large query. Apparently the database takes long enough to respond that I get the "a script on this page may be busy" popup. Moreover, the entire browser (Firefox) locks up while it's waiting. I thought the whole point of AJAX was to load stuff unobtrusively.

I've looked through the tutorials and documentation for EasyUI but it's not clear to me how to force a datagrid to load in the background. There are some similar unanswered questions asked on the EasyUI forums.

Do I need to override the loader property of datagrid? 
If so, does anybody know where I can get a non-obfuscated version of the default loader function so I can be sure I understand what it's supposed to do before I write my own?

Also, if I need asynchronous datagrids and datatrees with sorting and filtering features, is jQuery EasyUI the wrong library for doing this simply and cleanly? Is there some alternative jQuery library people would recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, if I need asynchronous datagrids and datatrees with sorting and filtering features, is jQuery EasyUI the wrong library for doing this simply and cleanly? Is there some alternative jQuery library people would recommend?

It turns out that the answer is to use jqGrid (an addon to jqueryui) instead of easyui datagrid. It does proper asynchronous queries out of the box, has all the other features I need, the switch was fast and painless, and I have no regrets about whatsoever about migrating from easyui.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at [DataTables](http://datatables.net). I have used it and found it to be a fantastic datagrid plugin with all the features that you are looking for.